# Is AWS amplify secure on mobile devices(flutter/ios/android)?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile, aws-amplify

I would like to know how secure is AWS amplify on mobile devices, especially in apps developed with **flutter**?

For me it's not clear if a device is **rooted**, is there something which stops the attacker to use amplify to access the AWS infrastructure directly?

Comment: The `amplifyconfiguration.json` and `awsconfiguration.json` files contain information about the Cognito pools that the app uses. You could pull out these IDs, and interact with the pools in your own application. Amplify does store session/access/ID tokens, but they are encrypted. The attack vector to decrypt these tokens would be more intricate. Amplify JS doesn't encrypt them. Some relevant reading on that is here: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/3436

Comment: Thank you for the explanation Jameson.